# Nexus 5 won't share internet connection anymore

Tags: networking, internet, android

I used Nexus 5 to share Internet connection to my laptop via USB. It worked well but suddenly on one day it stopped shared the connection, and it has never shared the connection since then. How can I debug this problem? My nexus 5 has Android version 6.0 and Ubuntu has the following version:

```
jaakko@jaakko-Aspire-E1-572:~/programming$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
jaakko@jaakko-Aspire-E1-572:~/programming$ uname -a
Linux jaakko-Aspire-E1-572 4.0.0-040000-generic #201504121935 SMP Sun Apr 12 23:36:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use Tethering USB and it will works! Just tried now with Google Nexus 5 connected via USB cable on a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. You'll find that setting into Settings - Others - Tethering Hotspot or something similar (my OS is in italian).